# Tool for debugging KVO/Bindings in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

Is there any tool to log current observers of a given object, in the spirit of what "gdb info gc-roots" does? I found "gdb info gc-references" could do that (sort of) as a by-product of its original purpose, but that won't work with non garbage collected apps. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you mean observers in the KVO sense, consult TN2124. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECFOUNDATIONOTHER

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at the F-Script Object Browser. http://www.fscript.org/

It allows you to inspect your objects (not only views) at runtime and display the it's property and binding information.